# Unable to pipe and pass through cmdlets to another?

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

The script below was meant to be working to gather the mailbox size of Exchange Online.

```
    $Mailboxes = @('User1.name@domain.co.uk', 'user2.name@company.com') + GetEXOMailbox | Where-Object {$_.Name -like '*User*'}
        
    $folderAndSubfolderSize = @{n='FolderAndSubfolderSize'; e={[math]::Round(($_.FolderAndSubfolderSize.Replace(',', '') -replace '.*?\((\d+)\s+bytes\)', '$1') / 1MB, 1)}}
$DisplayName = @{n='Display Name'; e='Identity'}

$Mailboxes | Get-EXOMailbox | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name | ForEach-Object {
    Write-Host "Processing $_ ..." -ForegroundColor Yellow
   Get-EXOMailboxFolderStatistics -Identity $_ |
      Where-Object {$_.Name -like "Top of Information Store"} |
      Select-Object -Property $DisplayName, $folderAndSubfolderSize, ItemsInFolderAndSubfolders |
      Where-Object {$_.FolderAndSubfolderSize -gt 1 }
} | Out-GridView
```

However, the error below is stopping the result to be displayed properly.

```
Get-EXOMailboxFolderStatistics : Identity is a mandatory value to provide for running Get-ExoMailboxFolderStatistics. You can specify identity by using either of the following
Identity, ExternalDirectoryObjectId, UserPrincipalName.
At line:6 char:2
+     Get-EXOMailboxFolderStatistics $_.Name |
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ProtocolError: (:) [Get-EXOMailboxFolderStatistics], RestClientException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Identity is a mandatory value to provide for running Get-ExoMailboxFolderStatistics. You can specify identity by using either of the following
Identity, ExternalDirectoryObjectId, UserPrincipalName.
,Microsoft.Exchange.Management.RestApiClient.GetExoMailboxFolderStatistics
```

I wonder how can that be fixed?

Comment: Use the `-identity` parameter when calling the command. The documentation does not mention that any of the parameters accepts value by position number (position 0 in your attempt)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation for each parameter of [Get-EXOMailboxFolderStatistics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/get-exomailboxfolderstatistics?view=exchange-ps) states that the position of each parameter is `Named`.  Therefore you must use `-Parameter Value` to bind a value to a parameter.

```
Get-EXOMailboxFolderStatistcs -Identity $_.UserPrincipalName
```

What you tried relies on a numeric position for the `-identity` parameter. By default, functions enable positional parameters in the order they are declared. You can explicitly disable positions using `PositionalBinding` argument of the `CmdletBinding` attribute. You can also set positions using the `Parameter` attribute. See [Advanced Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced_parameters?view=powershell-7).

Comment: Hi @admin, the error still the same.
The code works up until:
$Mailboxes | Get-EXOMailbox | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name

I have updated the code, so far there is no error, but the console only shows the Processing User DisplayName only?

Comment: Your first `where-object` uses `()` instead of `{}`

Comment: Yes, that's a good finding :-)
However, the issue remains the same?.

Comment: In `$mailboxes`, you are mixing strings with mailbox objects in the same array. That wouldn’t be best practice. Maybe you should consider selecting the `userprincipalname` value for your `get-exomailbox` command

Comment: OK, thanks for the pointer, it is almost working. How to remove the \Top Of Information Store in front of the User display name row content?

Comment: Just use `-replace` -> `$_.Identity -replace '\\Top of Information Store'`.

Comment: the Display Name column is now empty with this:
$DisplayName = @{n='Display Name'; e="Identity -replace '\\Top of Information Store'"}

Comment: It should be `e={$_.Identity -replace '\\Top of Information Store'}}`